# Fixing the code (multiple variable, loop & object literal)

Tags: javascript, loops, object, literals

I wanted to change the original code (multiple variable w/ loop) into an object literal. And yes I know you can't run loop in an object literal, but seeing multiple variable give me a pet peeve.

Here the original code

```js
var fruits, text, fLen, i;

fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits[6] = "Lemon"; // this is the code that got deleted
fLen = fruits.length;
text = "<ul>";
for ( i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";
  }
text += "</ul>";
document.write(text);
```

And the new code

```js
var fruitOrder = {
    fruit : ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"],
    //fLen : fruits.length, --moved to for loop--
    text : "<ul>",
    loop : function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.fruit.length; i++) {
        this.text += "<li>" + this.fruit[i] + "</li>";
        }
        this.text += "</ul>";
        document.write(this.text);
    }
};
fruitOrder.loop();
```

Both the original & new code work, but the problem is I accidentally deleted the `fruits[6] = "Lemon";` while I was changing the code.
And I've tried many way to put it in and make it work, but it wouldn't give me the output I wanted it to return:

- Banana Orange Apple Mango undefined undefined Lemon

Comment: you can add loop function to prototype of Object

Comment: @MaciejKozieja What does that have to do with getting `"Lemon"` into the `fruits` array?

Comment: @Barmar Not creating new function to evry object posible

Comment: @MaciejKozieja If he has multiple of these, he should create a `Fruit` prototype, not add to `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @Barmar yes that's true

Answer (score 0):

You can leave gaps in an array literal if you want an element further out.

```js
var fruitOrder = {
    fruit : ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", , ,"Lemon"],
    //fLen : fruits.length, --moved to for loop--
    text : "<ul>",
    loop : function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.fruit.length; i++) {
        this.text += "<li>" + this.fruit[i] + "</li>";
        }
        this.text += "</ul>";
        document.write(this.text);
    }
};
fruitOrder.loop();
```

Or you can add to the array after creating the object.

```js
var fruitOrder = {
    fruit : ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"],
    //fLen : fruits.length, --moved to for loop--
    text : "<ul>",
    loop : function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.fruit.length; i++) {
        this.text += "<li>" + this.fruit[i] + "</li>";
        }
        this.text += "</ul>";
        document.write(this.text);
    }
};
fruitOrder.fruit[6] = "Lemon";
fruitOrder.loop();
```

Comment: downvoting for helping ? upvoted. Whats wrong going on here Wishes for 300k :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I don't let it bother me, I have plenty of rep to spare.

Comment: I'll take the 2nd code since I want to be able to change the number anytime to `fruits[6] = "Lemon";` thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
fruitOrder.fruit[6]= "Lemon";
```

Will do

```js
var fruitOrder = {
    fruit : ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"],
    //fLen : fruits.length, --moved to for loop--
    text : "<ul>",
    loop : function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.fruit.length; i++) {
        this.text += "<li>" + this.fruit[i] + "</li>";
        }
        this.text += "</ul>";
        document.write(this.text);
    }
};
fruitOrder.fruit[6]= "Lemon"; 
fruitOrder.loop();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Lemon` to always be at index 6, you could use a javascript closure to modify the fruit object before returning the object:

```js
var fruitOrder = (function() {
  var data = {
    fruit: ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"],
    //fLen : fruits.length, --moved to for loop--
    text: "<ul>",
    loop: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.fruit.length; i++) {
        this.text += "<li>" + this.fruit[i] + "</li>";
      }
      this.text += "</ul>";
      document.write(this.text);
    }
  };
  data.fruit[6] = "Lemon";
  return data;
})();
fruitOrder.loop();
```

Comment: But I want to be able to change the number anytime to `fruits[6] = "Lemon";`, but thank for the suggestion ^.^

Comment: @user7021951 That makes sense. Thanks for clarifying. I updated the answer to be more in line with that.